# Is it possible to make an interactive map like uber does using Flutter?

Tags: react-native, mobile, flutter, maps

I have a project coming this December. It is an e-commerce website which has a delivery system. If a customer orders an Item from the shop, the delivery boy will deliver the Item to the customers location. While delivering the item, the delivery boy should follow a direction or route in a map going to the customer's location.

And in the customer's side, the customer can also monitor or check the delivery boy's location in a realtime.

My question is: **Is it possible to do that in Flutter? **. Because in react native they said that it is very possible.

Im still in a decision stage which to framework to use that can answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, definitely, because Flutter let you write your own widgets if you need to. Everything is possible, provided you have enough resources (time, money...)
The more adequate question would be: which one is the more convenient / the fastest to get your application out.

My feeling at this day is that Flutter ecosystem is much smaller than ReactNative's. 
Airbnb `react-native-maps` provide you with a map with many features / bugfixes you don't have to code, and I don't see a library with as many features on Flutter's side.

There are generally less third-party libraries on Flutter, whereas you have a ton of it with ReactNative. 
Also, it's easier to find a developer that knows Javascript than Dart.